# Django and Loading Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm setting up a Bootstrap Carousel working from a Django-powered image database. I have no errors in the console log, jQuery is loading, etc., so I'm definitely missing something painfully obvious. It does not transition to other slides, and the controls are not working either. I have tried loading the carousel library separately, and nothing seems to work. <strike>I'm using jQuery 1.11.0 loaded via CDN from Google.</strike> I'm using jQuery 1.11.3 served via Static files in Django. The error seems to be in how Django is loading the varied Javascripts, but I'm not savvy enough to determine what the issue is.

ETA:

I am loading bootstrap.min.js after jQuery. I normally have some custom JS running, but I've removed that script for testing.

Here's the Django code generating the carousel:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"> 
        </head>
        <body>
            {% include "menu.html" %}
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="panel panel-primary shadow-normal">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                {% for image in index_carousel %}
                                    {% if forloop.first %}
                                        <li data-target='#mycarousel' class='active' data-slide-to='{{ forloop.counter }}'></li>
                                    {% else %}  
                                        <li data-target='#mycarousel' data-slide-to='{{ forloop.counter }}'></li>
                                    {% endif %} 
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            {% for image in index_carousel %}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    <div class="item active">
                                {% else %}
                                    <div class="item">
                                {% endif %}
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ image.carousel_image.url }}" alt="Carousel Slide - {{ image.alt_text }}">
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- Carousel -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            setTimeout( function() {
                $('#mycarousel').carousel();
            }, 15000)
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here's the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="panel panel-primary shadow-normal">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target='#mycarousel' class='active' data-slide-to='1'></li>
                                <li data-target='#mycarousel' data-slide-to='2'></li>
                                <li data-target='#mycarousel' data-slide-to='3'></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/carousel_images/staff_blogs.png" alt="Carousel Slide - ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/carousel_images/aarp-tax-help-slide_ZznUFS2.png" alt="Carousel Slide - ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/carousel_images/august_book_sale_new.png" alt="Carousel Slide - ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Controls -->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div> <!-- Carousel -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready( function() {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        $('#mycarousel').carousel();
                    }, 15000)
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The error I consistently get is

```
$(...).carousel() is not a function.
```

What could be the issue here? All the files are being found, and I've tried timeouts to make sure everything is loaded, but to no avail. I'm running this same setup served via PHP/MySQL, and it works, so the *only* variable is Django. Is there something I'm missing with loading the static files?

Comment: Are you including bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: @NikhilBatra - Yes. The js loads as follows - jQuery, then Bootstrap.

Comment: have you try to set a timeOut to delay the call on your carousel ?

Comment: @Beauceron - I tried a 1 second timeout, and got the same $(...).carousel() is not a function error. I'll up the time a bit to see if it's just a timing issue. ETA: At 15 seconds, the error remains.

Comment: You should make a jsfiddle and see if it's work. Maybe something else in the page make your thing doesn't work.

Comment: @Beauceron - as it stands, the only thing on the page is the Carousel, the essential javascript links, and the Django template code. I've got the same code running on a PHP framework without errors, so I'm thinking the error comes in how Django is loading the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please include the above lines, its working fine if I include the above.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: See the modified question - all those files are loaded, though I'm using 1.11.3 on jQuery because of compatibility with other parts of the site.

Comment: Please check by including all the 3 links that I have specified in the comment and revert. Since its working fine if I include those 3 links

Comment: That's extremely strange; It works, but why would it work with the files loaded from external sources, but not served from the local static files, as the files are - apart from branding colors in the CSS - exactly the same?

Comment: You might have downloaded different or lower versions of jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: I tried this with the files downloaded to the static directory rather than served from the CDNs, and it's again not working. It does work if the CSS is local, though, with the CDN versions of the Javascript, which works for my purposes - though I'd like to know why it doesn't work served locally as I have several locally hosted scripts that need to work for the site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85125/discussion-between-ksk-and-slink).